# JavaScript: Conditionally process fetch response

Tags: javascript, json, conditional-statements, fetch, arrow-functions

I have a fetch() request returning a Response object that is either a zip file (blob) or a JSON if there was an error with the request. The code I have successfully processes the zip file and sends it to the users Downloads folder. When a JSON response is returned, the code creates a empty/corrupt zip file.

How would I go about conditionally processing the Response object so that it prevents a file from being downloaded if it is a JSON? I would also like to store Response.json() in a variable?

```
await fetch(params)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
   let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   let a = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = url;
   a.download = name + ".zip";
   document.body.appendChild(a); 
   a.click();
   a.remove();  //afterwards we remove the element
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: If there was an error with the request, the catch block should handle that. When you log out the blob, what does it show you?

Comment: @SterlingArcher The `catch` block only catches communication errors, not errors reported in the response value.

Comment: @Barmar ah a returned error, right. Sounds like they just need to check for the error with an `if` then?

Comment: @SterlingArcher That's what they're asking how to do. The problem is that the data format is different -- you have to know whether it's an error or not so you know whether to call `res.json()` or `res.blob()`. It's circular.

Comment: You can try calling `res.json()`. If that gets an error, call `res.blob()`.

Comment: @kfly2fly So how can you distinguish the zip response from the error json response? By HTTP status? By HTTP content-type header? By something else?

Comment: @Barmar No, that won't work either, you can read a response body only once

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I realized that problem when I tried to code it -- if `res.json()` fails I couldn't figure out how to get the original response to call `.blob()`.

Comment: Can you redefine the API? It would be better if it always returned JSON. This can have an `error: boolean` flag, and the zip contents can be in another property.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions all. Per @Barmer and @Bergi suggestions I was able to redefine the API so that my error content is now just inside of a header. The solution I found looks like this:

```
await fetch(params)
.then(function(response) {
   if (response.headers.get('X-Error') == 'False') {
      return response.blob()
         .then(blob => {
            let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = name + ".zip";
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
         }).catch(err => console.error(err))
   }
   //process error from backend
   console.log(response.headers.get('X-Error'))
})
```

Comment: Why use a non-standard header? The HTTP status is designed for this.

Comment: I plan on passing information through this variable other than 'Success' or 'Failure' (ie file size and other file metadata). I don't have a whole lot of experience with HTTP header standards but I thought it easiest to create my own header. Perhaps I'm wrong in this though

Comment: Put the status (success vs error) in the status, e.g. 200 or 404. Put the kind of response in the `content-type` header, e.g. `application/json` vs `application/zip` or `application/octet-stream`. The file size goes into the `content-length` header (there's no way around), but you can also just access [`blob.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size). Extra error information goes into the body.